# Foreach loop runs forever ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to load `QuestionsComponent` components based on the No of questions received in the props;

Functionality works but application hangs after something, In console I could see the `console.log(steps);` getting logged infinite times.

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Please help

```
const DynamicForm: React.FC<any> = ({ questions }) => {
  const q: any = [];
  const [steps, setSetps] = useState([]);
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const refs = useRef<(HTMLDivElement | null)[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    questions.forEach((question: any) => {
      q.push(QuestionsComponent);
    });
    setSetps(q);
    console.log(steps);

    scrollToComponent(refs.current[step], {
      offset: -100,
      align: 'top',
      duration: 1000,
    });
  }, [steps, questions, step, q]);

  return (
    <div>
      {steps
        .filter((_: any, index: any) => index <= step)
        .map((Step: any, index: any) => (
          <Step
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            key={index}
            question={questions[index]}
            domRef={(ref: any) => { refs.current[index] = ref; }}
            toPrev={() => {
              scrollToComponent(refs.current[index - 1]);
            }}
            toNext={() => {
              if (step === index + 1) {
                scrollToComponent(refs.current[index + 1]);
              }
              setStep(index + 1);
            }}
            setStep={setStep}
            step={index}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is because you are watching `q`, `steps` for `useEffect` and updating it within it. Which will cause useEffect to trigger again.  You can remove it from dependency array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your useEffect hook has `steps` as a dependency which means it runs every time you call setSteps. You happen to call setSteps inside useEffect which renders the component continously and causes an infinite loop.

You could either remove steps as a dependency or add a conditional check:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if(steps.length) return;
    questions.forEach((question: any) => {
      q.push(QuestionsComponent);
    });
    setSetps(q);
    console.log(steps);

    scrollToComponent(refs.current[step], {
      offset: -100,
      align: 'top',
      duration: 1000,
    });
  }, [steps, questions, step]);
```

Comment: I created a stackblitz, I'm still getting infinite loop https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-caasck

Comment: Remove `q` as a dependency.

Comment: Your implementation appears way over-engineered imo. See my approach: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-duapfs?file=app.tsx

Comment: @Hyetigran did a good job of solving your problem. let us know if your problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The resolve answer is like what @Hyetigran. I only add several tips to prevent something like this happen in the future.

1. use ESLint with strict settings
2. use Prettier to support the ESLint function
3. install the plugin of both inside your IDE

With those things installed properly, you should get a warning when an infinite loop is happen in your code, and the suggestion would come out of the warning message.

Comment: I created a stackblitz, I'm still getting infinite loop https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-caasck?file=app.tsx